# Fluent: Table name different from entity name

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to use the automapping feature of Fluent with nHinbernate to map a class with a different name than the table itself is name.

(This is purely for stylistic reasons we have a class named Foo which contains an object named Bar but the table name is FooBar. We would rather not have a property Foo.FooBar.)

I can't find anything detailing how to give Fluent a clue on this change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With classmap you can specify the table name in the [mapping](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started#Mappings).

```
public class BarMap : ClassMap<Bar>
{
    public BarMap()
    {
        Table("FooBar");
    }
}
```

With automap you can override the table name.

```
.Mappings( m => m.AutoMappings.Add( AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Bar>()
    .Override<Bar>( b => {
        b.Table("FooBar");
}))
```

You can also use [conventions](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions) to affect table naming of all entities.

Comment: Not really what we are looking for. We are trying to still automap the assembly. We don't want to create a manual mapping for the class only specify a different table name for one specific entity.

Comment: @Matt the second example uses automap and only changes the table name for a single entity

Comment: yep that is what I was looking for found it about a minute before you posted it too. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the table name in the mapping. So it will look something like this:

```
public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
  Table("FooBar");

  // Rest of your mapping goes here.
}
```